# Fab should hide or unhide through java when some action is performed

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have taken a floating action button, initially its visibility is gone, throught xml. after some payment is done, which i opened in an web view, on success, that fab should be visible to the user which is in another activity. how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a reference to the FAB in your code. Then you can use setVisibility() to hide or show the button.

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private View mFloatingActionButton;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaces) {
         super.onCreate(savedinstances);

         this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_here);
         this.mFloatingActionButton = this.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

     }

     // This is some method in your code called when you want to show the button
     public void onSomeActoion() {
         // This makes the FAB visible
         this.mFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the payment activity, you can set a boolean flag in the `SharedPreferences` like `paymentSuccesful` to either be `true` or `false` and in the other activity, retrieve the value from sharedPreference and try to set the visibility on the `fab` based on the result from sharedPreference. i.e

```
if (paymentSuccessful) {
  fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
  fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Make sure you are setting the visibility after you get the value from the sharedPreference.